# How I should fix java-path, in order to run tomcat?

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I installed tomcat, set variables `CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat and CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat`. in terminal I entered command which java and got response `/usr/bin/java`. So how I understand this is path for JAVA_HOME. I set it. When I start tomcat  in terminal with `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` I get response:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

But when I check, I see that tomcat wasn't started and in logs I found:

```
/opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/bin/java/bin/java: not found
```

I suppose,that something wrong with path to java. How can I fix it?
PS everyhing was performed in Ubuntu OS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should point your JRE_HOME to the directory where your java is installed, not the executable `java` itself. An example would be
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle` where that folder will contain the `bin/java` executable...

Comment: and you're right. I changed the path to JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle and tomcat started

Answer (score 4):

You can also edit the file `../bin/setclasspath.sh` and have an entry

```
JAVA_HOME="##path of the java directory##"
```

This will make sure whenever you try to start the tomcat, the `JAVA_HOME` will be enforced.

Answer (score 4):

When the tomcat is started it is searching for setenv.sh in Catalina home or base.

Quote from Catalina.sh:

```
#   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
#   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.

#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.

# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi
```

So best way to set JAVA_HOME in tomcat is through setenv.sh

1. create a file setenv.sh in $CATALINA_HOME folder
2. Add this line to it : "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/"
3. Make it executable : "chmod 750 setenv.sh"

Start the startup.sh script, it will start the tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up *JAVA_HOME* property in /etc/default/tomcat7:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

This will force Tomcat to use JVM located under /usr/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

For C shell (csh), edit the startup file (~/.cshrc):
`set path=(/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin $path)`
For bash, edit the startup file (~/.bashrc):

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:$PATH
```

export PATH
For ksh, the startup file is named by the environment variable, ENV. To set the path:

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:$PATH
```

export PATH
For sh, edit the profile file (~/.profile):

```
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.7.0/bin:$PATH
```

export PATH
Then load the startup file and verify that the path is set by repeating the java command:

For C shell (csh):

```
% source ~/.cshrc<br>
% java -version
```

For ksh, bash, or sh:

```
% . /.profile<br>
% java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu

Set JAVA_HOME in **.bashrc** as export **JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/**
and run **. .bashrc** then start tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

This one solved my issue:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1018063

PS: I installed tomcat8 by ***apt-get*** instead of downloading the compressed tomcat file.